# Having an issue dealing with numeric and special characters on Coderbytes Letter Changes exercise

Tags: javascript

Hello I have not been able to find anything that addresses the issue I am having so far.
In this exercise, the only thing which should be changed is alphabetic characters. However, in the test cases, it includes numbers and special characters which get changed as well and they shouldn't be.

I have the following code:

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

    let newTxt = ""; // stores string after changing each character to the next in the alphabet
    let newTxt2 = '';
    //iterate through the string
    for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){

        switch(str[i]){
            case ' ':
                break;
            case 'z':
                newTxt = 'a';
                break;
            case 'Z':
                newTxt = 'A';
                break;

            default:
                newTxt = newTxt.concat(String.fromCharCode(str.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0) + 1));
                break;
        }

        //uppercase vowels
        switch(newTxt.charAt(i)){
            case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
                newTxt2 += newTxt.charAt(i);
                break;
            default:
                newTxt2 += newTxt.charAt(i);
                break;

        }
    }
    str = newTxt;

    return str; 

}
```

The default of the first switch statement could I use an if/else or nested switch to make it to where if the current character equals a special character or number using regular expression, just add the character back without changing and if it's not change?

I am still new to Javascript. I have been searching Google for over an hour.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution after a few hours of research and trying different things:

```
const LetterChanges = str => {
   let newTxt = str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(c){
       switch(c){
           case 'z': return 'a';
           case 'Z': return 'A';
           default: return String.fromCharCode(1+c.charCodeAt(0));
       }
   });
   return newTxt.replace(/[aeiou]+/g, function(vowel){
        return vowel.toUpperCase();
   });



}
```

Thank you